Como puedo hacer para que mi app permita cobrar con decimal?
Buen día, Como puedo hacer para que mi app hecho en php vue y mysql permita cobrar con decimal (0.50). Como se ve en la imagen me sale error:

Esta es la funcion cobrar de mi codigo:
     cobrar(mesa){
        this.$buefy.dialog.prompt({
            title: `Cobrar a la mesa #` + mesa.mesa.idMesa,
            message: `El cliente debe pagar $` + mesa.mesa.total,
            inputAttrs: {
                type: 'number',
                value:"",
                placeholder: 'Escribe la cantidad con la que paga',
                min: 1
            },
            trapFocus: true,
            onConfirm: (value) => {
                if(parseFloat(value) < parseFloat(mesa.mesa.total)){
                    this.$buefy.toast.open({
                        message: 'Escribe una cantidad correcta',
                        type: 'is-warning'
                    })
                    return
                }

                this.cargando = true
                let cambio = parseFloat(value - mesa.mesa.total)

                let payload = {
                    idMesa: mesa.mesa.idMesa,
                    cliente: mesa.mesa.cliente,
                    total: mesa.mesa.total,
                    pagado: value, 
                    idUsario: mesa.mesa.idUsuario,
                    insumos: mesa.insumos,
                    atiende: mesa.mesa.atiende
                }
                
                HttpService.registrar(payload, "registrar_venta.php")
                .then(registrado => {
                    if(registrado){
                       this.$buefy.dialog.alert({
                            title: 'Venta registrada',
                            message: 'Gracias por su compra, su cambio <b>$' + cambio + '</b>',
                            confirmText: 'OK'
                        })
                        this.imprimirComprobante(payload)
                        this.crearMesas()
                        this.cargando = false
                    }
                })
                
            }
        })
    },

Ya intente poniendole en el inputAttrs que el min sea a partir de 0.01, y cuando le pongo eso me sale que solo permite valores 10.01 o 11.01, y no deja colocar enteros tambien cuando le pongo ese valor al min.

Has probado a poner en el inputAttrs.min = 1.0?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

desde el desconocimiento absoluto y siendo más nuevo que mañana.
Has probado a poner en tu función el type float?

Gracias, que tonto... no me percate de ese detalle. me funciono tanto el metodo de arriba como el de ti. Se agradece la ayuda, Buend dia.

@Deivintir trata de editar tu respuesta, agrega una descripción más completa y explicativa, además de mostrar el código modificado que tu sugieres. Recuerda que siempre puedes añadir modificaciones, mejoras, etc. Pero siempre primero es atender el problema del otro usuario primero. Mirate [ask] para más información, o consulta directamente.

Revisar [answer], saludos.

Cambia el input, eso es lo que debes hacer.
Primero, haz que el input sea un text, para ingresar lo que quieras.
Luego, agrega un pattern con regex, para admitir los decimales.
Y agrega luego el inputmode:'decimal', para los usuarios mobiles.
inputAttrs: {
        type: 'text',
        value: "",
        placeholder: 'Escribe la cantidad con la que paga',
        pattern: "[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?",
        inputmode: 'decimal',
        min: 1
    }

Mas abajo, cuando revises el valor, lo parseas a lo que quieras. En este caso, a float controlando el decimal.
const montoPagado = parseFloat(value.replace(',', '.'));

Puedes además, realizar una validación simple con IF. Por ejemplo, que sea número y mayor o igual al monto de la mesa.
if (isNaN(amountPaid) || montoPagado >= parseFloat(mesa.mesa.total))


muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho. Buen día.

@CristhianAntonyCisnerosRodr no agregues gracias.. acepta la respuesta que te sirivio...
